# Not able to replace SQLite table with RSQLite/DBI package

Tags: r, sqlite

I'm trying to overwrite a table in a SQLite database with a new table and I get following error message that I do not understand and I wasn't able to find a answer online so far:

```
RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: duplicate column name: row_names)
```

Below I created some simplified sample code to replicate my problem:

```
library(RSQLite) # will load DBI as well

## open a connection to a SQLite database
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("SQLite"), dbname = "testDB.db")

# save internal R dataset in database as table
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcarsTab", mtcars, overwrite = T)

# subset database table and store as data frame
subDf <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcarsTab WHERE cyl = 4")

# try to replace old table with new table
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcarsTab", subDf, overwrite = T)
```

Resulting output of the last statement is:

```
> dbWriteTable(con, "mtcarsTab", subDf, overwrite = T)
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In value[[3L]](cond) :
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: duplicate column name: row_names)
```

Comment: Add `row.names=FALSE` to your `dbWriteTable` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferred from comments: Add `row.names=FALSE` to the `dbWriteTable` calls